# How do I create a conditional SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, syntax, conditional-statements

I am trying to create an Oracle Sql query using IF/Else statements

```
IF EXISTS 
  ( 
         SELECT * 
         FROM   baninst1.an_employee_position 
         WHERE  baninst1.an_employee_position.person_uid = 593791 
         AND    baninst1.an_employee_position.position_end_date IS NULL) THEN 
  SELECT * 
  FROM   baninst1.an_employee_position 
  WHERE  baninst1.an_employee_position.person_uid = 593791 
  AND    ( 
                baninst1.an_employee_position.position_end_date IS NULL 
         OR     baninst1.an_employee_position.position_end_date > SYSDATE) 
  AND    baninst1.an_employee_position.effective_start_date <= SYSDATE;ELSE 
  SELECT * 
  FROM   ( 
                SELECT * 
                FROM   baninst1.an_employee_position 
                WHERE  baninst1.an_employee_position.person_uid = 593791 ) 
  WHERE  ROWNUM = 1;END IF;
```

However I receive an "Unknown Command" error when I run it. No more error information

Comment: What exactly are you trying to achieve?

Comment: I would like to know if the employee is active and if they are not active, the last position held by the employee.This table holds records of every position an employee has held. When the position_end_date is null then that is the employee's current position. If the  position_end_date is not null then the employee has been terminated but in order to get the last position held I have to sort by the effective_start_date and choose the first one.

Comment: Oracle SQL doesn't have IF ELSE, it has CASE and DECODE. PLSQL has IF ELSE and SWITCH statements

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This may provide what you are looking for:

```
SELECT a.* 
 FROM employee_position a
where person_uid = 593791
and (
      (a.position_end_date is null)
      or
      (
        a.position_end_date =
        (select max(position_end_date)
         from employee_position b
          where b.person_uid = a.person_uid
          and b.position_end_date is not null
        )
      )
    )
```

Another way

```
SELECT a.* 
 FROM employee_position a
where person_uid = 593791
and (
      nvl(a.position_end_date, trunc(sysdate+100)) >= 
      (select max(position_end_date)
       from employee_position b
       where b.person_uid = a.person_uid
       and b.position_end_date is not null
      )
    )
```